# pm2 is not recognized as an internal or external command, in Github Action

Tags: node.js, github-actions, pm2

I added a self hosted runner in github action. i want to deploy my code with pm2.
My workflow file.

```
runs-on: self-hosted
strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [ 15.x ]
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  - name: check pm2 list
    run: .\a.bat
```

a.bat file contains simple command.

```
pm2 list
```

Run .\a.bat

```
  .\a.bat
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
```

```
C:\actions-runner\_work\Sooperwizerfrontend\Sooperwizerfrontend>pm2 list 
  'pm2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have already install pm2.
This command working properly on my powershell.
like.
pm2 list

```
 PS C:\actions-runner> pm2 list
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
└─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

run on my power shell.

Comment: Probably the `PATH` environment variable is not correct.

Comment: environment variable set but not working